# How to insert images to bodytext in tx_news using ckeditor in TYPO3 8.7.X

Tags: ckeditor, typo3, typo3-8.x, tx-news

I am trying to add the ability to add images using the `rte_ckeditor_image` plugin in the `news` plugin. I have done all the steps described in the manual (creating an RTE folder, adding a code fragment to the `ext_localconf.php` file) but the possibility of adding photos is still missing.

I am doing something wrong or the plugin of the `news` will not handle it?

P.S. Is there any way to run the `rte_ckeditor_image` ext globally or do I have to configure each plugin separately?

Comment: I've seen from the code that there is also a static typoscript to load (typoscript template > edit whole record > include static from extension).

Comment: Hi, after loading the TS code nothing has changed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using the following configuration and it works well even in news:

**FullAndImage.yaml**

```
# Load default processing options  
imports:
    # Import default RTE config (for example)
    - { resource: "EXT:rte_ckeditor/Configuration/RTE/Full.yaml" }
    # Import the image plugin configuration
    - { resource: "EXT:rte_ckeditor_image/Configuration/RTE/Plugin.yaml" }

# Add configuration for the editor
# For complete documentation see http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config
editor:
  config:
    removePlugins: null
  externalPlugins:
      typo3image:
        allowedExtensions: "gif,jpg,jpeg,png,svg"
```

**in ext_localconf.php:**

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['RTE']['Presets']['default'] = 'EXT:my_extension/Configuration/RTE/FullAndImage.yaml';
```

I never configured CKEditor especially for `news`.

**EDIT:**
Still one tip: if you upgraded TYPO3 and still have PageTS for the old editor `rte_htmlarea` then it's the best just to delete the old configuration. It's able to mess some things up in the new editor `rte_ckeditor`. I don't know if someone verified which old parameters are disturbing or have which impact in the new editor, therefore just deleting of old configuration is the simplest solution.

Comment: I cleaned PageTS from old entries and from the configuration: `RTE.default.preset = full`, changed the location of the entry in ext_localconf.php (above `$ boot = function ()`) and the plugin worked